# Unable to run Python with Apache on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, ubuntu, webserver

Unable to run python with apache on Ubuntu as the following:

sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xxxx
        ServerAlias xxxx
        <Directory /var/www/xxxxr>
                Options +ExecCGI
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
                Allow from all
                DirectoryIndex index.py
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxx
</VirtualHost>
```

index.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from server import config
from server import sio
from server import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sio.run(app, debug=config.debug, host=config.host, port=config.port)
```

URL testing result (http://xxxxxx.com):

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Apache Log:

```
[Sat Mar 05 02:05:42.064545 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 738117] [client 185.254.196.223:35262] AH01215: : : /var/www/xxxx/index.py
[Sat Mar 05 02:05:42.064650 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 738117] [client 185.254.196.223:35262] AH01215: No module named flask_socketio: /var/www/xxxx/app.py
[Sat Mar 05 02:05:42.064713 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 738117] [client 185.254.196.223:35262] AH01215: : /var/www/xxxx/index.py
[Sat Mar 05 02:05:42.066495 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 738117] [client 185.254.196.223:35262] End of script output before headers: index.py
```

Note: a run app with python3 index.py is working as normal

Comment: is it related to the access level of a script or related files? you can try `chmod 777  filename` on your files.

Comment: I am already granted chmod 777. It is the still the same error.

Comment: Have you looked in the error log, as the message suggested?

Comment: I think the problem is because your `python` is mapped to another version of python which is not the same as your `python3`. you can check this by comparing their output of `which python` and `which python3`

Comment: which python
/usr/bin/python

which python3
/usr/bin/python3

Comment: remove previous apache and install it with this: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` let me know if it works; I can write the answer.

Comment: you can also map `python` to python 3 by adding this line `alias python='/usr/bin/python3'` to the end of file `~/.bashrc` and then running `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Hi @SadraNaddaf. still error.
which python
/usr/bin/python

installed sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 but not working.

Comment: So it means still you have not mapped `python` to python3. once mapped the `python` should show `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: python --version
Python 3.8.10

Comment: So probably my guess is not working if you have access to Flask with both